# When I try to connect a website A, Instead of going to that website It should redirect me to the ADFS 3.0 Single Sign On

Tags: asp.net, adfs

Scenario :

When I try to connect a website A, Instead of going to that website It should  redirect me to the ADFS 3.0 Single Sign On. After Successful Sign on, I should be redirected to homepage of Website A

I need an explanation in C#/ASP.NET

Comment: Response.Redirect("http://www......"); or Server.Transfer("....aspx", true);

Comment: I have to wireup a website with ADFS

Comment: I hope you answer works... @Dr.Geek.
Thanks

Comment: Hey @Dr.Geek, It didn't help

Comment: @Dr.Geek 
Here is the answer.. I found it..
I am just posting it for reference
http://developers.de/blogs/armin_kalajdzija/archive/2016/10/06/how-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs-in-asp-net-mvc-using-owin.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my question...

http://developers.de/blogs/armin_kalajdzija/archive/2016/10/06/how-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs-in-asp-net-mvc-using-owin.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**To redirect a user to another page by using the browser:**

1. Set the Response object's BufferOutput property to true.
2. Call the Response object's Redirect method, passing it the URL of the page to which you want to redirect users.

Sample code:

```
Response.BufferOutput = true;
if (UserLanguage == "English")
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.website.com/gohere/look.htm");
}
else if (UserLanguage == "Deutsch")
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.website.com/gohere/look_deu.htm");
}
else if (UserLanguage == "Español")
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.website.com/gohere/look_esp.htm");
}
```

**To redirect users to another page by using a server-side method:**

1. Call the Transfer method, passing it the name of the page to which you want to redirect users.

Sample code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx", true);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry to say this is not the answer I am looking for!!  @Ank